# Select keys and values between 2 keys Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary

```
{'first': 1, 'el1': 2, 'el2': 2, 'last': 999}
```

I want to select all the items between the specified keys(first and last in this example) how could I do that

Comment: Are you defining "between" as alphabetical order, or the order the keys appear in the dictionary?

Comment: Not alphabetical order

Comment: What ordering do you mean? The order they print out (which for recent versions of Python will be insertion order), or the order of the values? This problem is underspecified, so you may get answers that don't address what you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator where an iterator is created for the dict items so that items until the first key can be skipped, and then items until the second key are yielded:

```
def items_between_keys(d, k1, k2):
    items = iter(d.items())
    for k, _ in items:
        if k == k1:
            break
    for k, v in items:
        if k == k2:
            return
        yield k, v
```

so that:

```
d = {'first': 1, 'el1': 2, 'el2': 2, 'last': 999}
for k, v in items_between_keys(d, 'first', 'last'):
    print(k, v)
```

outputs:

```
el1 2
el2 2
```

Alternatively, use a flag to indicate that the first key has been found before yielding:

```
def items_between_keys(d, k1, k2):
    found = False
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k == k1:
            found = True
        elif k == k2:
            return
        elif found:
            yield k, v
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little homemade version of accomplishing this. We take the keys, `first-last`. Then we create a new list with those keys and there values in the original dictionary.

```
dct = {'first': 1, 'el1': 2, 'el2': 2, 'last': 999}

kys = list(dct.keys())
kys = kys[kys.index('first')+1:kys.index('last')]
newDict = {k:dct[k] for k in kys}
print(newDict)
```

output

```
{'el1': 2, 'el2': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Python is 3.7 or newer, you can guarantee that the order is preserved. Anything older, the keys may be stored in a random, hashed order.

You can get all the keys in a `dict` using `keys()`. You would then loop over the keys, starting when you find the starting key, and break out of the loop after you find the ending keys.

I initially wrote this as a snippet, but decided to interpret "select" as adding to a new dictionary. The logic is the same.

```
def select_between(src_dict, start_key, end_key):
    result, selected = {}, False
    for key, value in src_dict.items():
        if not selected:
            if key != start_key:
                continue
            selected = True
        result[key] = value
        if key == end_key:
            break
    return result
```

Using your example,

```
select_between({'first': 1, 'el1': 2, 'el2': 2, 'last': 999},
               'el1', 'last')
```

will give you

```
['el1': 2, 'el2': 2, 'last': 999}
```

--B

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to get the list of keys in your original dictionary, find the indices of your starting key and ending key, and build a new dictionary from the original using a dictionary comprehension:

```py
>>> d = {'first': 1, 'el1': 2, 'el2': 2, 'last': 999}
>>> keys = list(d.keys())
>>> i = keys.index("first")
>>> j = keys.index("last")
>>> result = {k: d[k] for k in keys[i:j+1]}
>>> result
{'first': 1, 'el1': 2, 'el2': 2, 'last': 999}
>>> i = keys.index("el1")
>>> j = keys.index("last")
>>> result = {k: d[k] for k in keys[i:j+1]}
>>> result
{'el1': 2, 'el2': 2, 'last': 999}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
> dict={'first': 1, 'el1': 2, 'el2': 2, 'last': 999}
> for key,value in dict.items():
>     if (key!="first") &(key!="last"):
>         print (value)
```

See here:[image]

Comment: You shouldn't use `&` for boolean comparisons, the keyword `and` is much more appropriate. The parentheses around the inequality sub-conditions would then be unnecessary. I'm also not sure you're actually solving the questioner's problem for anything other than their example dataset. If there were any key-value pairs before `'first'` or after `'last'`, you'd print them too.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to do this in-place:

```
d = {'first': 1, 'el1': 2, 'el2': 2, 'last': 999}
d.pop('first')
d.pop('last')
```

if you want to preserve the initial dict:

```
d = {'first': 1, 'el1': 2, 'el2': 2, 'last': 999}
res = {k: v for (k,v) in d if key not in ['first', 'last']}
```

Comment: "between the specified keys". Presumably there can be keys after "last" and before "first"

Comment: I disagree, already, using the word "between" for dictionary keys makes 0 sense in Python. One could state that more recent version of python keep the keys in the creation order, OrderDicts too, BUT I would not use a dictionary structure and do a "search keys between x and y", this is the wrong structure for this. UNLESS we're doing an alphabetical search between keys. Hence my answer.

Comment: All currently supported versions of CPython maintain insertion order. Python 3.5 and 2.7 haven't been supported since last year.